OriginalRepliedMessageSender doesn't show on the body of the webhook in Twilio for whatsapp
I am trying to trigger a specific pipeline for when a user answers one of my texts, however the body that I am getting doesn't contain OriginalRepliedMessageSender nor OriginalRepliedMessageSid.
My webhook is an standard fastapi implementation.
Any help is appreciated thanks
This is my webhook
@app.post("/twilio-webhook") async def twilio_webhook(request: Request): form_data = await request.form()

It seems your code is not complete. Can you check out the Debugging Tools in the console and see if the right parameters are specified there?
